# Autoselect first free port in JerseyTest

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I'm using `jersey-test-framework-grizzly-1.19.4` to test web services. From time to time I see failed tests due to the exception `com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException: java.net.BindException: No free port within range`. From source code I see that Jersey always uses port 9998 for starting server socket. Of course this port might be occupied by other tests running in parallel. Is it possible to tell Jersey to use any free port from arbitrary range?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom port by setting `jersey.config.test.container.port` property, which is conveniently declared as [TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/8dcbaf4b5cb0fb345eb949acfa66b1fbe09d1ffb/test-framework/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/TestProperties.java#L92). The property is read by `JerseyTest` on [initialisation](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/8dcbaf4b5cb0fb345eb949acfa66b1fbe09d1ffb/test-framework/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.java#L732).

Naturally the property must be set prior to initialisation of `JerseyTest`.